# How to make difficult group with count on C# (linq)?

Tags: c#, linq, file, grouping

I have trouble with text analysts.
Need to count words iteration in .txt files
I made it, but I need to put all counts together without separating on files.

How to rewrite with grouping correct?

```
var queryMatchingFiles =
            from file in files
            where file.Extension == ".txt"
            let fileText = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName)
            let matches = Regex.Matches(fileText, searchTerm)
            select new
            {
                matchedValues = from Match match in matches
                                group match by match.Value into grp
                                select new {
                                    key = grp.Key, value = grp.Count()
                                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
var queryMatchingFiles =
            from file in files
            where file.Extension == ".txt"
            let fileText = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName)
            from match in Regex.Matches(fileText, searchTerm).Cast<Match>()
            group match by match.Value into grp
            select new
            {
                key = grp.Key,
                value = grp.Count()
            };
```

To create `IEnumerable<Match>` from matches you can use:

```
Regex.Matches(fileText, searchTerm).Cast<Match>()
```

So you can write query like `from match in ...`

Another option to cast is by explicitly specifying the type in expression:

```
from Match match in Regex.Matches(fileText, searchTerm)
```